# How to show two random strings from separate arrays in one <p> tag

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and I am trying to make two random strings that were selected by using math.random() and put them into my p tag so that I could end up with something like 'Storm Breaker' or 'Castle Eater', but it seems I can only display the first name (fname) or the last name (lname). I tried to do

```
document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=fname,lname;
```

That didn't work so I also tried:

```
document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=fname;
document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=lname;
```

But as you could tell that would just change where the first name would be into the last name.

```
<h1 class="title">Welcome to Tom's Random Name Generator!</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction();">Generate!</button>

<p id="print"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var fnamel = ['Storm','Wind','Castle','Chocolate','Savage'];
    var lnamel = ['Breaker','Eater','Smasher','Killer','Fury'];

    var fname = fnamel[Math.floor(Math.random()*fnamel.length)];
    var lname = lnamel[Math.floor(Math.random()*lnamel.length)];

    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=fname;  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change like this :

```
 document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=fname + " " + lname;
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Welcome to Tom's Random Name Generator!</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction();">Generate!</button>

<p id="print"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var fnamel = ['Storm','Wind','Castle','Chocolate','Savage'];
    var lnamel = ['Breaker','Eater','Smasher','Killer','Fury'];

    var fname = fnamel[Math.floor(Math.random()*fnamel.length)];
    var lname = lnamel[Math.floor(Math.random()*lnamel.length)];

    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=fname + " " + lname;  
}
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate strings in javascript using the plus operator.

```
  document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=fname + ' ' + lname;
```